# java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset while using select statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have following piece of code in which i am trying to create user id's ad jdoe, jdoe1, jdoe2, etc.
for which I am checking uniqueness(or existence of user id against a sql table). I keep on getting Exhausted resultSet error. I understand that is happening because the select query did't find "jdoe" (which is good) but I am unable to handle it.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM t_av_accounts WHERE name = ? ");
    ResultSet rs = null;

/*Some more code here*/

ret = builder.toString();
        log.debug("** Start SUFFIX: " + suffix.toString() + "&& ret: " + ret);
        while(x){
            pstmt.setString(1, ret);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            if(rs != null){
                rs.next();
                if(rs.getString(1) == ret){
                    if(suffix==1)
                        ret.concat(suffix.toString());
                    else
                        ret.substring(ret.length()-1).concat(suffix.toString());
                ++suffix;
                log.debug("** Current SUFFIX: " + suffix.toString() + "&& ret: " + ret);
                }
                else{
                    ctx.setUserVariable(WorkflowContext.VariableLevel.Job, "AFXUSERCUSTOM_"+user.getId()+"_CUSTOM_USERID", ret.toLowerCase());
                    x = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect that your query didn't return any rows before doing anything to cause the exception to be thrown. The [API documentation for ResultSet.next](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) says:

> When a call to the next method returns false, the cursor is positioned after the last row. Any invocation of a ResultSet method which requires a current row will result in a SQLException being thrown.

Currently your code is discarding the value returned by `rs.next`, have your code check the return value instead. If it's false then there are no rows returned and you can avoid calling `rs.getString(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my while loop:

```
while(x){
            pstmt.setString(1, ret);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            if(!rs.next()){
                ctx.setUserVariable(WorkflowContext.VariableLevel.Job, "AFXUSERCUSTOM_"+user.getId()+"_CUSTOM_USERID", ret);
                x = false;
            }
            else{
                rsName = rs.getString(1);
                if(suffix==1)
                    ret = ret.concat(suffix.toString());
                else
                    ret = (ret.substring(0,ret.length()-1)) + suffix.toString();
                ++suffix;
                log.error("** Current SUFFIX: " + suffix.toString() + " && ret: " + ret + " && rsName that found: " + rsName);
            }
        }
```